# 'Error executing query' when analyzing cube on Saiku Analytics

Tags: plugins, schema, pentaho, olap, saiku

I've installed Plugin Saiku on Pentaho Bi Server 5.0.1 , and successfully adding cube by published it from schema workbench. The problem is I couldn't analyze the data from my cube.

[image: Error displayed by Saiku]

It said error executing query, but there is no error in the schema I made on schema workbench.

Then i tried to move to MDX mode, and running query. It shows same error.
[image: Error displayed by Saiku]

So I concluded there is something wrong with the connection to the database. But I don't know how to solve it.
Is there any solution for it?

Answer (score 1):

I just found the solution to my problems. The error occur because I hadn't set JDBC in my Data Source. When I published from Schema Workbench, it only adding ANALYSIS data source without the JDBC. We have to manually set it up. It required on Pentaho BI Server version 5.x.
Here's link to show how to publish & set up cube in detail for Pentaho Bi Server 5.x >> http://pentaho.phi-integration.com/bi-server/publish-schema-pada-bi-server-versi-5